# sencha touch :: useClearIcon listener in searchfield

Tags: search, field, listener, sencha-touch

is there a way to listen to the event, when the user clicks/tabs on the clearIcon in a seachfield?

unfort. the keyup and change listeners are ignored then...

thnx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have put the following code on the `onFirstActivate` method of the panel:

```
var clearIconEl = this.getEl().down('[class="x-field-clear-container"]');
clearIconEl.on('click', this.handleClearIconClick, this);
```

this catches the clear icon click, though it depends on its undocumented css class.

UPDATE:
I see two much more elegant solutions to this same problem at [sencha touch textfield clear event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343006/sencha-touch-textfield-clear-event)
I think I will use one of them myself...