# How to handle tap event on sencha searchfield 'Clear' (X) icon?

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs, sencha-touch-theming

i am trying to handle event on tap of clear button on sencha searchfield which appears there by default.
i couldn't find a listener to handle that event on sencha docs.
any help will be appreciated.

i referred this thread. [sencha touch textfield clear event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343006/sencha-touch-textfield-clear-event) but i dont want to display separate clear icon apart from the default clear icon displayed by searchfield.

thank you.

Comment: You will need to post some code so that people can give ideas / suggestions

Comment: `code`
ListDemo.searchField = new Ext.form.Search(
 {
    id: 'searchField',
    xtype: 'searchfield',
    placeHolder: 'Search',
    name: 'searchField',
    store: ListDemo.ListStore,
   
   /* onClearTap: function()
     {
         console.log('test clear');
         this.setValue('');
     }, */
    //useClearIcon: true,
    /* onClearIconTap: function() {
     if (!this.disabled) {
      this.setValue('');
      console.log('onClearTap: Clear button tapped!');                       
     }
    } */
`code`     
i wish to handle the 'X' icon tap event for this searchfield.

Answer (score 0):

you can clear that  by using  function `clearFilter()`