# Override a system event: textfield clear

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I've got many TextFields in my app, all with the same problem:
After pressing the clear-icon in the right the focus of this textbox is lost.

[This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343006/sencha-touch-textfield-clear-event)  works but is not efficient, because then I'd have to do it for every textfield:

```
                {
                    xtype: 'textfield',
                    label: 'Name',
                    onClearIconTap: function() {
                                        this.setValue('');
                                        console.log('onClearTap');
                                    }
                }
```

I've come across [this page](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?124405-How-to-detect-when-someone-clears-a-textfield), overriding the event, but it doesn't work. This would be a preferred solution:

Any help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An even nicer solution (works with touch 2.3.0) :

```
Ext.define('MyApp.override.field.Text', {
    override: 'Ext.field.Text',
    // @private
    doClearIconTap: function(me, e) {
        me.setValue(this.originalValue);

        me.focus();

        //sync with the input
        me.getValue();
    }
});
```

Comment: true, and possibly make an extra class file for this in a map overrides.

Answer (score 3):

Here's how to override the function, inside the app.js launch-function for Sencha Touch 2:

```
Ext.field.Text.override({
        onClearIconTap: function() {
            this.setValue('');
            this.focus();
            console.log('global onClearTap');
        }
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QYJpc/46/